# No se ejecuta el segundo insert con PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tengo un problema el cual no he podido solucionar. Resulta que recibo unos datos de la pasarela de pagos PAYU y quiero generar el registro de la venta, sin embargo solo se guardan los datos en la tabla venta pero no se guardan los items en la tabla detalle.

Cuando se hace de forma normal a través de la pasarela no se ejecuta el segundo insert pero cuando lo hago de forma manual, quemando los datos en la sentencia, si se ejecutan ambos insert. Tampoco se debe a un error de sintaxis ya que MYSQL no detecta ninguno cuando lo pruebo en MYSQL Workbench. El servicio de hosting que estoy utilizando es 000webhost.

Les agradezco que me ayuden a encontrar el problema.

Aquí dejo el código en PHP.

```
<?php

/* CONECTAR A LA BASE DE DATOS */
include_once "database/conexion.php";
$obj = new Conexion();
$conexion = $obj->conectar();

$state_pol=$_REQUEST['state_pol'];
$correo_usuario=$_REQUEST['email_buyer'];
$id_pais=$_REQUEST['shipping_country'];
$ciudad=$_REQUEST['shipping_city'];
$departamento=$_REQUEST['extra2'];
$cod_postal=$_REQUEST['extra1'];
$direccion_calle=$_REQUEST['shipping_address'];
$fecha=$_REQUEST['transaction_date'];
$total=$_REQUEST['value'];
$ref_pago=$_REQUEST['reference_pol'];


//SI LA TRANSACCIÓN ES CORRECTA SE CREA LA VENTA Y EL DETALLE
//$state_pol=4;
if($state_pol==4){
    
    
$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);

//ESTE FUNCIONA A LA PERFECCION


//INSERTO LA VENTA
$query_venta = "INSERT INTO venta (
correo_usuario,
total_venta,
fecha_venta,
estado_venta,
id_pais,
departamento,
ciudad,
direccion_calle,
cod_postal,
reference_pol)

VALUES('$correo_usuario',$total,'$fecha',0,'$id_pais','$departamento','$ciudad','$direccion_calle','$cod_postal','$ref_pago')";
$res= $conexion->prepare($query_venta)->execute();
    
//ESTE NO SE EJECUTA

//INSERTO EL DETALLE DE LA VENTA
$values="";
foreach($_SESSION['items'] as $item=>$value){//RECORRO EL CARRO DE COMPRAS

$id_producto=$value['id_prod'];
$cantidad_detalle=$value['cantidad_prod'];
$precio_unitario_detalle=$value['precio_prod'];
$sub_total_detalle=$precio_unitario_detalle * $cantidad_detalle;
        
$values.= "((SELECT MAX(id_venta) FROM venta),$id_producto,$cantidad_detalle,$precio_unitario_detalle,$sub_total_detalle),";

}
    
$values=rtrim($values,",");
$query_detalle = "INSERT INTO detalle (id_venta,id_producto,cantidad_detalle,precio_unitario_detalle,sub_total_detalle)VALUES $values";
$res_detalle=$conexion->prepare($query_detalle)->execute();
    
    
//VACIAR CARRO DE COMPRAS
$_SESSION['items']=array();

}

?>
```

Comment: Qué error te está dando?

Comment: Haz un `echo $query_detalle;` y dinos qué muestra. Sea como sea, deberías considerar el uso de consultas preparadas para dar seguridad a tu código y no activar NUNCA las preparaciones emuladas. Te estás exponiendo gravemente a ataques de *Inyección SQL*.

Comment: No me muestra ningún tipo de error. Hago un echo de la venta y del detalle. `INSERT INTO venta ( correo_usuario, total_venta, fecha_venta, estado_venta, id_pais, departamento, ciudad, direccion_calle, cod_postal, reference_pol) VALUES( 'carlos.velez@gmail.com', '45000', '2021-12-01 14:28:56', '0', 'CO', 'Antoquia', 'Medellin', 'CLL 75 - 789', '200025', 'TEST' )`

Comment: Y del detalle me da esto `INSERT INTO detalle ( id_venta, id_producto, cantidad_detalle, precio_unitario_detalle, sub_total_detalle ) VALUES ( (SELECT MAX(id_venta) FROM venta), '38', '1', '148500', '148500' );`

Comment: Pero lo más extraño de todo es que antes del detalle quiero obtener el ultimo id insertado `$ultimo=$conexion->lastInserId();` y este siempre me retorna 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probablemente es un problema de comillas simples al construir la consulta y al intentar ejecutarlo el motor de DB no puede. hay que hacer un echo de las consultas construidas y ensayarlas en el motor de DB.

Comment: Ya encontré la causa del problema, las sentencias SQL están bien, lo que no lee es la variable $_SESSION['items'], estoy usando payu webcheckout pero solo me registra la venta y no el detalle almacenado en la session